# Python: TypeError: String indices must be integers while parsing JSON

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing

I have written a code to parse through the following json content but I am getting error message as "TypeError: String indices must be integers".[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3MBT.png)

```
import urllib
import json
while True:
    url = raw_input('Enter url: ')
    if len(url) < 1 :break
    info = json.loads(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
    counts = 0
    total = 0
    print info
    for value in info:
        if value['count']:
            e = value['count']
            for value in e.itervalues():
                print value
```

JSON

```
   {
  "comments":[
    {
      "name":"Leven",
      "count":100
    },
    {
      "name":"Mahdiya",
      "count":97
    },
    {
      "name":"Ajayraj",
      "count":87
    },
    {
      "name":"Lillian",
      "count":86
    },
    {
      "name":"Aon",
      "count":86
    },
    {
      "name":"Ruaraidh",
      "count":78
    },
    {
      "name":"Gursees",
      "count":75
    },
    {
      "name":"Emmanuel",
      "count":74
    },
    {
      "name":"Christy",
      "count":72
    },
    {
      "name":"Annoushka",
      "count":72
    },
    {
      "name":"Inara",
      "count":72
    },
    {
      "name":"Caite",
      "count":70
    },
    {
      "name":"Rosangel",
      "count":70
    },
    {
      "name":"Iana",
      "count":66
    },
    {
      "name":"Anise",
      "count":66
    },
    {
      "name":"Jaosha",
      "count":65
    },
    {
      "name":"Cadyn",
      "count":65
    },
    {
      "name":"Edward",
      "count":63
    },
    {
      "name":"Charlotte",
      "count":61
    },
    {
      "name":"Sammy",
      "count":60
    },
    {
      "name":"Zarran",
      "count":60
    },
    {
      "name":"Rowen",
      "count":59
    },
    {
      "name":"Stanislaw",
      "count":59
    },
    {
      "name":"Maighdlin",
      "count":57
    },
    {
      "name":"Connan",
      "count":56
    },
    {
      "name":"Warrick",
      "count":54
    },
    {
      "name":"Diya",
      "count":52
    },
    {
      "name":"Lawson",
      "count":52
    },
    {
      "name":"Wu",
      "count":51
    },
    {
      "name":"Irmak",
      "count":47
    },
    {
      "name":"Emilija",
      "count":47
    },
    {
      "name":"Kayda",
      "count":41
    },
    {
      "name":"Ellenor",
      "count":41
    },
    {
      "name":"Kyra",
      "count":41
    },
    {
      "name":"Nikita",
      "count":38
    },
    {
      "name":"Kaelah",
      "count":35
    },
    {
      "name":"Meko",
      "count":32
    },
    {
      "name":"Marissa",
      "count":31
    },
    {
      "name":"Ayat",
      "count":24
    },
    {
      "name":"Sali",
      "count":19
    },
    {
      "name":"Hashem",
      "count":19
    },
    {
      "name":"Tygan",
      "count":18
    },
    {
      "name":"Rioden",
      "count":17
    },
    {
      "name":"Cruiz",
      "count":16
    },
    {
      "name":"Caoilfinn",
      "count":13
    },
    {
      "name":"Ewen",
      "count":8
    },
    {
      "name":"Baighley",
      "count":7
    },
    {
      "name":"Ramone",
      "count":1
    },
    {
      "name":"Kyran",
      "count":1
    },
    {
      "name":"Noelani",
      "count":1
    }
  ]
}
```

Tell me a way to add all the values in the **count** (Json content)

Comment: Looks like you didn't parse the json

Comment: How to add all the values in **count**

Comment: @Madhan did you mean, `counts += e` ?? btw what is `info`??

Comment: Please post your actual code. The current code doesn't show where you parse the JSON string data. Presumably, that's what's in `info`, but we can't help you if we have to guess what your code is. Also, post the full traceback of your error message (in a code block to preserve formatting); merely saying "I am getting error message" is not helpful.

Comment: Thanks, that's _much_ better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over the list of dictionaries in the `"comments"` item of your JSON object. I'll use a short version of your data to illustrate.

```
info = {
    'comments':[
        {'count': 100, 'name': 'Leven'},
        {'count': 97, 'name': 'Mahdiya'},
        {'count': 87, 'name': 'Ajayraj'},
        {'count': 86, 'name': 'Lillian'},
        {'count': 86, 'name': 'Aon'},
        {'count': 78, 'name': 'Ruaraidh'},
        {'count': 75, 'name': 'Gursees'},
        {'count': 74, 'name': 'Emmanuel'},
        {'count': 72, 'name': 'Christy'},
        {'count': 72, 'name': 'Annoushka'},
        {'count': 72, 'name': 'Inara'},
    ]
}

total = 0
for d in info['comments']:
    name, count = d['name'], d['count']
    total += count
    print name, count, total
print total
```

**output**

```
Leven 100 100
Mahdiya 97 197
Ajayraj 87 284
Lillian 86 370
Aon 86 456
Ruaraidh 78 534
Gursees 75 609
Emmanuel 74 683
Christy 72 755
Annoushka 72 827
Inara 72 899
899
```

Answer (score 1):

It's asking for an integer because a JSON data is a dictionary containing lists of dictionaries.  Look at your format of "value" (print value).   You'll see that count is a member of a list.  To call a specific member of a list, you call it by index number (an integer) not by a string.  Here's an example of your data structure after json.loads():

```
{u'comments': [{u'count': 100, u'name': u'Leven'}, {u'count': 97, u'name': u'Mahdiya'}, {u'count': 87, u'name': u'Ajayraj'}, {u'count': 86, u'name': u'Lillian'}, {u'count': 86, u'name': u'Aon'}, {u'count': 78, u'name': u'Ruaraidh'}, {u'count': 75, u'name': u'Gursees'}, {u'count': 74, u'name': u'Emmanuel'}, {u'count': 72, u'name': u'Christy'}, {u'count': 72, u'name': u'Annoushka'}, {u'count': 72, u'name': u'Inara'}, {u'count': 70, u'name': u'Caite'}, {u'count': 70, u'name': u'Rosangel'}, {u'count': 66, u'name': u'Iana'}, {u'count': 66, u'name': u'Anise'}, {u'count': 65, u'name': u'Jaosha'}, {u'count': 65, u'name': u'Cadyn'}, {u'count': 63, u'name': u'Edward'}, {u'count': 61, u'name': u'Charlotte'}, {u'count': 60, u'name': u'Sammy'}, {u'count': 60, u'name': u'Zarran'}, {u'count': 59, u'name': u'Rowen'}, {u'count': 59, u'name': u'Stanislaw'}, {u'count': 57, u'name': u'Maighdlin'}, {u'count': 56, u'name': u'Connan'}, {u'count': 54, u'name': u'Warrick'}, {u'count': 52, u'name': u'Diya'}, {u'count': 52, u'name': u'Lawson'}, {u'count': 51, u'name': u'Wu'}, {u'count': 47, u'name': u'Irmak'}, {u'count': 47, u'name': u'Emilija'}, {u'count': 41, u'name': u'Kayda'}, {u'count': 41, u'name': u'Ellenor'}, {u'count': 41, u'name': u'Kyra'}, {u'count': 38, u'name': u'Nikita'}, {u'count': 35, u'name': u'Kaelah'}, {u'count': 32, u'name': u'Meko'}, {u'count': 31, u'name': u'Marissa'}, {u'count': 24, u'name': u'Ayat'}, {u'count': 19, u'name': u'Sali'}, {u'count': 19, u'name': u'Hashem'}, {u'count': 18, u'name': u'Tygan'}, {u'count': 17, u'name': u'Rioden'}, {u'count': 16, u'name': u'Cruiz'}, {u'count': 13, u'name': u'Caoilfinn'}, {u'count': 8, u'name': u'Ewen'}, {u'count': 7, u'name': u'Baighley'}, {u'count': 1, u'name': u'Ramone'}, {u'count': 1, u'name': u'Kyran'}, {u'count': 1, u'name': u'Noelani'}]}
```

You'll see that count is in a dictionary that is the first item in a list.  You need to access that list, THEN access the count key of that dictionary.